# Как передать значение переменной из Bash в PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Есть PHP-скрипт, который вызывает системные команды; в нём нужно обработать некоторые данные, которые должен ввести пользователь. Пример на Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Enter something:'
read someString
echo ${someString}
```

---

Как получить значение переменной `someString` в PHP?

---

**Не работает**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Enter something:' . "\n";
system('read someString');
echo exec('echo ${someString}') . "\n";
```

**Не работает**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Enter something:' . "\n";
system('read someString');
echo getenv('someString') . "\n";
```

**Не работает**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Enter something:' . "\n";
$someString = exec('read someString');
echo $someString . "\n";
```

**Не работает**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Enter something:' . "\n";
$someString = shell_exec('read someString');
print_r($someString);
```

---

Единственный вариант, который я нашёл в [интернете](https://sitepoint.com/community/t/can-i-get-variables-from-a-shell-script-into-php-variables), это сохранить значение переменной в файл, а потом достать его оттуда:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Enter something:' . "\n";
system('read someString; echo -n ${someString} > /tmp/some-string');
$someString = file_get_contents('/tmp/some-string');
system('rm /tmp/some-string');
echo $someString . "\n"; // It works!
```

<s>Седьмое чувство подсказывает, что это делается не так.</s>

Comment: А вариант, скрипт на баше передает через конвейер значение на вход пхп скрипта, подойдет?

Comment: @defrag, мне кажется, что это только усложнит код, так как, например, в моём случае скрипт долго работает, а в конце спрашивает (или вариант, когда спросить нужно несколько раз в течение выполнения).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так надо дергать bash через функцию shell-exec() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Это тоже не работает. Забыл добавить в вопрос. Сейчас добавил.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov `$someString = shell_exec('read someString; echo $someString');`

Comment: Точно )) Можно и `exec()` ...